# Contact us button in php telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I created a button in my telegram bot named "contact us". How can I get the member's message after pressing "contact us" button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every message that user type and sends, your bot receives it.
But if your question is how your bot can recognize that user press specific key "`contact us`", answer is this: When someone touch that button, its caption (`text`) field will send automatically to your bot e.g. "`contact us`" string will send automatically to your bot.

Comment: Thanks, but for example one member press "contact us" and then write "Thanks for bot". I want to have this . I cannot use if($text==="Thanks for bot") <use sendMessage methods to send member message to me>. Because member can write every things. Sorry I am beginner in php.

Comment: Also i known that first use this: if($text==='contact us'){<send user's text to me>}. But in situation, user's text is "contact us" !!!

Comment: @aminroshani I couldn't understand your question very well but keep in mind: 1)KeyboardMarkup does have only text(one text) and when you press it, then it send this text. 2) I think your issue is this: when you send keyboard, scripts end and quit. when user press that key or do something else actually telegram runs your script again from start whith user's given data.

Comment: Thank you. When user send keyboard, scripts end and quit. After send keyboard bot waiting for insert text(e.g. Thanks for bot) from user. Ok, User send Thanks and I have a new data from user, well how I can save this new text? User send every message and I cannot use : if($text==="XXX"){<send text to me>}

Comment: @aminroshani this is another question but in short and as a key answer, You should create a database(like MySQL) and save for each user something.Each user has a UNIQUE identifier that telegram sends in each message that your bot receives .As you know it is `chat_id`. grab it and save it to your DB. then compare each message that you receive with it and user's previous  commands.